# Animation choppy when multiple animations running at once

Tags: android, performance, animation, conflict

I am working on some Android animation effects. On one screen there are several background images fading in/out constantly, and there is also a text marquee. The problem is that the text marquee is kind of choppy. When the image fade in/out is disabled, the marquee is smooth, so it is likely the 2 animations are affecting each other.

I am wondering if there is a way out other than writing my own animation by using `Canvas` or `SurfaceView`.

I took a look at `AnimationSet`, but that is only good for combining animations for the same view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while but here are the things I have found along the way:
To achieve smooth text scrolling animation, it needs about 50 frames per second. So it really stretches the CPU out. I tried to use a surfaceView to do both the image and text animation, and managed to get to 35 frames per second but that was not enough, the text scrolling is still a little jumpy. I read a little opengl and it looks like OpenGL ES 2.0 should be able to handle the image fade in/out in parallel ways. But did not really go through with it. Hope this helps.